# How to "GET" the right value from a mixed form with different actions?

Tags: php, html, forms

When I write a form like this:

```
<table>
  <form>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="newText" type="text" .../></td>
    <td><input type="submit" .../></td>
  </tr>
  </form>
  (repeat the above row several times for dynamically generated content)
</table>
```

That's incorrect HTML (a warning error is generated in the IDE) and I'm not sure if it will work correctly across all browsers.

I can't put them in seperate tables because that just ruins all the formatting; widths of td's vary across each table depending on the content.

So then I bring the whole form out of the table like this:

```
<form>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="newText"/></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="action" value="action1"/></td>
  </tr>
  (repeat rows several times with different values for the 'action' button)
</table>
</form>
```

Now the problem is that, the last generated record rubs over the `newText` value, and so when the form is submitted from the first row, the submitted params look like this:

> newText = text1
>   action = action1
>   newText = text2
>   newText = text3
>   newText = text4

So I know that I need to perform `action1` but all I ever get is `text4` as the value!

How do I get the right value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
newText2 = text2
newText3 = text3
.
.
.
```

or `name="newText[]"`

Comment: Ohh, so I set the name with [] and then I can access all the variables like an array?